# Pilot light on gas log fireplace extinguishes when turn gas control knob to "on"

Tags: pilot-light

When preparing my gas log fireplace (Marco model 794153B) for use in cold weather, my pilot light will ignite easily and stay on when release pushing in the control knob, but when I try to turn the control knob to the "on" position, the pilot light extinguishes.  My memory from use of my fireplace last year is that the pilot light stays on throughout the season and only extinguishes when I turn the control knob to "off" at the end of the season.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the gas valve and of the pilot assembly? If you cant imbed pics using the "edit" feature, place them on Imgur and edit the links/filepaths into your question and we will embed the pictures for you.

Comment: Thank you.  I’ve been trying to upload photos but keeps saying too big.  I don’t know what Imgur is.

Comment: I’ve googled Imgur and will try to use it tomorrow to upload a photo.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Once you light the pilot hold it there for up to a minute then turn to on.
It is possible the thermal pile or thermocouple is not quite hot enough.
I find giving it a minute usually works if it still goes out and the flame is hitting the probe of the TC it is time for a new one.

The good thing is they are inexpensive and easy to change.

Comment: Thank you.  Once the pilot light is lit I have continued to press on the button for a minute before releasing.  The pilot stays lit when I release it and I’ve waited another minute before switching to “on”.  As soon as I switch to on the pilot light goes out

Comment: Ed Beal is right. Thermocouple probably needs replacing.